# OKD Install fails on prereqs configuring SELinux with docker

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

This has happened on over 12 machines now.  Both older configured CentOS7 machines and brand new ISO installs.

When i run the OKD prerequisites install, branch `release-3.11`, I get everything running fine until I get to task

`TASK [container_runtime : Fixup SELinux permissions for docker]`

where it fails with this

```
{
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/docker/overlay2 \"/var/lib/docker/overlay2\"\n restorecon -R -v \"/var/lib/docker/overlay2\"",
    "delta": "0:00:00.005386",
    "end": "2019-03-22 15:52:19.990999",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/docker/overlay2 \"/var/lib/docker/overlay2\"\n restorecon -R -v \"/var/lib/docker/overlay2\"",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2019-03-22 15:52:19.985613",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: semanage: command not found\n/bin/sh: line 1: restorecon: command not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: semanage: command not found",
        "/bin/sh: line 1: restorecon: command not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I have been stuck at this for nearly a month now.  I have done everything up to and including scrapping our corp centos7 image (it was built to have SELinux disabled) and build a new one from scratch.  Nothing seems to work.  The thing that really irritates me the most, is if i take those two command lines, ssh into the target box and do

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/docker/overlay2 "/var/lib/docker/overlay2"
sudo restorecon -R -v "/var/lib/docker/overlay2"
```

it runs perfectly fine.

Here's my inventory file

```
all:
  children:
    etcd:
      hosts:
        cent1.lab.mycompany.com:

    masters:
      hosts:
        cent1.lab.mycompany.com:

    nodes:
      hosts:
        cent1.lab.mycompany.com:
          openshift_node_group_name: node-config-master-infra
        cent2.lab.mycompany.com:
          openshift_node_group_name: node-config-compute
          openshift_schedulable: True
    OSEv3:
      children:
        etcd:
        masters:
        nodes:
      vars:
        openshift_deployment_type: origin
        openshift_master_cluster_method: native
        openshift_master_cluster_hostname: console.lab.mycompany.com
        openshift_master_default_subdomain: apps.lab.mycompany.com

        ansible_ssh_user: automation_user
        ansible_become_method: sudo
        ansible_become: true
        ansible_become_flags: '-S'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a permission or PATH problem with the ansible user this should be fixed by using the `--become` flag for ansible playbook execution using `--become` or `-b` with according `--become-method=sudo` and `--become-user=root`. This should setup PATH correctly so that `restorecon` and `semanage` can be found.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/become.html

`restorecon` and `semanage` are usually stored in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` which is not in $PATH for a regular user. Using `sudo` and `become` with `root` should setup $PATH properly so that the executables can be found.